# python-chess: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chess.uci'

Tags: python, python-chess

I'm trying to run a [program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/Chess/Demo_Chess_AGAINST_AI.py) that requires the modules chess and chess.uci.

I do the "py -m pip install chess", but get the error message

File "D:\Pythonfiler\sjakk\PySimpleGUI\Chess\Demo_Chess_AGAINST_AI.py", line 7, in 
import chess.uci
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chess.uci'

Anyone got an idea what I could do? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to use `pip install python-chess` or is "**chess**" a different librarie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo script is old and was built at 24 Oct 2018, some steps required to run.

- Download the StockFish Chess engine at: https://stockfishchess.org/download/, and unzip it to a holder, it is required to provide the path of the specified file when script start.
- This script come with some png files, so you cannot run it directly, try to https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI and download zip file `PySimpleGUI-master.zip` under button `Code`, then unzip to a holder where you can find the holder `PySimpleGUI-master\Chess` with script file and png files.
- Install python-chess==0.25.1 for old library used when demo script designed
- run the script `Demo_Chess_AGAINST_AI.py` under holder `PySimpleGUI-master\Chess`
- Need to set some parameters on the right side of GUI before you move any chess, or it will be failed.

Comment: Thanks! I had only tried python-chess==0.23.9, because that was the one stated in the "requirements.txt". Just curious: How did you discover that 0.25.1 was the correct one?

Comment: Both of modules `chess.pgn` and `chess.uci` included in 0.25.1

Comment: Updated to 0.23.9 to be same as in requirements.txt

Comment: Ok, 0.23.9 did not work for me, but 0.25.1 did.

Comment: Ok, let it be 0.25.1, it looks like 0.23.9 work for me ...

Comment: it's probably useful to read :
https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/issues/415